# How to convert invalid JSON like string with inconsistent quotes into a valid JSON using regex in Java?

Tags: java, json, regex, string-parsing

Here is a sample String. I am facing trouble particularly in the part `'rgba(71,13,226,0.47)'` as the commas are present. The same regex should also parse a JSON array like string.

```
varStr ="{
    red : {
        orange: 100,
        dates: {
            later: "4_WEEK",
            now:   "1_WEEK"
        },
        pink: {
            crimson : '#16gcvcn',
            lavender : '#47vdsaj',
            purple : '#h7465',
            baby pink : '#hd576',
            yellow : 'rgba(71,13,226,0.47)',
            magenta : 'rgba(211,25,25,0.01)'
        }
    }
}";
```

So far I have a series of regex replacements, But there are issues with my regex it does not handle all cases.

```
    varStr = varStr.replaceAll("([^:{,\"\\n =\\[}\\]][\\w &|\\/'.\\-)#]+)", "\"$1\"");
    varStr = varStr.replace("\"[", "[");
    varStr = varStr.replace("]\"", "]");
    varStr = varStr.replaceAll("'", "\"");
```

Comment: The commas in the `yellow` field are not a problem AFAIK...but the single quotes are, because that's not valid JSON.  You should go back to your source for this JSON and fix it.

Comment: yes, but I am allowed to modify the string, i.e replace the single quotes to double quotes. Perform the necessary modifications by adding quotes and replacing single quotes wherever necessary .@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: So, if I fully understand your question, you want a regex that can capture the keys and the values, in order to replace in your case `baby pink :` with `"baby pink" :`so it will become a valid **JASON**

Comment: Not just the `'rgba(71,13,226,0.47)'`, there are many parts will be incorrect such as `red` -> `"red "`, `"4_WEEK"` -> `""4_WEEK""` and so on with your regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to point out to you first, convert a string to a JSON one in this way is going to treat each value as `String`. Some datatypes such as `Number` or `Boolean` will be ignored and lose its convenience while deserialization.

You can achieve what you want as follows and I am going to update my solution if I could find a more elegant one!

**Code snippet**

```
String regex = "(?:[{ ])(\\w+)(?!\")";
varStr = varStr.replaceAll(regex, "\\\"$1\\\"");
varStr = varStr.replace("\"\"", " ").replace("'", "\"");
```

---

BTW, even though there is no standard naming convention for JSON, but I've never seen a field name separated by empty space(s). Therefore, it is better to use one of `babyPink`, `baby_pink` and `baby-pink`.

Comment: works beautifully! just what I was looking for. Thanks!